# Angular 4 : Catch back and forward browser button click and update page

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I am new to angular 4 and stuck with issue where page does not refresh if user clicks on back or forward browser button. query parameters in url changes as per history but page does not refreshes with previous results.  For example /search?text="ret" and back button it becomes /search?text=ben&tab=doc.

Need to refresh the 'search' route on browser button click. Tried using Location popstate event which captures the click but not able to refresh the page.

Setting window.location.href works but it reloads the page. Can ngrx router-store could be a solution?

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/v4.1.1/docs/router-store/api.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you do not need to refresh the page actually. That is all the thing about the Single Page Applications. Instead, try to change the page proactively in the `location.onPopState` handler. You can do even `router.navigate` there or parse popped query params, fetch and repopulate search results. You already know the new location, so act with this knowledge in-process.

Comment: Thanks I am using ngrx store and opened a new question for same. Thanks all for your response

Answer (score 0):

When the route's path remains the same, but the query params or route params are dynamic (change), the current component will not be destroyed and re-initialized. That is unless you flag the router to do so (Router.onSameUrlNavigation('reload') - see https://angular.io/api/router/Router).

For your case, you should subscribe to the route's query params, and react whenever new params are emitted.

eg.

```
subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {

    this.subscriptions.push(this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParamMap => {
        const text = queryParamMap.get('text');
        const doc = queryParamMap.get('doc');

        this.updateView(text, doc);
    }));
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
}
```

Only use route.snapshot as a shortcut when you know you won't need to handle dynamic route/query params.